# Percent Change as Predictor and Response variables?

Tags: mixed-model, percentage, controlling-for-a-variable

I am interested in the relationship between magnitude of change between two correlated variables i.e., after training, if performance increased by X%, does the %increase in task 1 predict the %increase in related task 2?

I have been unable to find a paper/source that discusses using %change as a predictor AND response variable with participant as a random effect. A colleague suggested I should use the post_variable as a predictor and control for baseline and an interaction post_variable*baseline (rather than just using %change). I am hoping someone can provide insight into which approach is better in this case and why.

I am running a mixed model using the lme package in R, so the two models look like this:

using raw pre/post scores and interaction:

clv <- lme(fixed = percent_clv ~ post_mip + pre_mip + pre_mip*post_mip,
data = all_data,
random = ~1|id,
method = "REML"

vs using percent change:

clv <- lme(fixed = percent_clv ~ percent_mip,
data = all_data,
random = ~ 1|id,
method = "REML",

Comment: Do the two percent change variables have the same denominator ?

Comment: No they don't have the same denominator, but they are airflow. One is cmH20 and one is in L/s. We know what is an expected %change in cmH20 (based on prior studies) but don't have an expected %change for the response variable in L/s